# Where is the JavaScript regular expression object test method documented?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've just come across this in javascript which seems to be testing for regular expressions:

```
/hello/.test("hello") //Returns true
```

However I cannot find the documentation for this, no matter what I search.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Regular expressions objects also have a method called [`.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

For future reference a search like "RegExp test mdc" will find you the documentation. Alternatively if you are brave you can search through the ES5 spec but that's a dry read.

Comment: There is some real distortion in upvotes, 5 in 30 seconds. You guys are crazy.

Comment: Apologies I did spend 15 mins prior to asking searching for an answer to no avail...maybe its one of those days.

Comment: @m.edmondson No, it's cool. Just saying appending your google search queries with "mdc" really helps to pinpoint it ;)